# Example of "$μ_n$ converges weakly to $μ$, but $μ$ is not absolutely continuous"

Tags: probability

Suppose that $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ be a sequence of probability distributions on $\mathbb{R}$ which are absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure. Give an example for: "it can happen that the probability distributions $μ_n$ are absolutely continuous w.r.t Lebesgue measure, $μ_n$ converges weakly to $μ$, but $μ$ is not absolutely continuous".

Answer (score 2):

Let $F_n(x)=0$ for $x<-1/n$, $=1$ on $x>1/n$, and the linear interpolation on $[-1/n,1/n]$. Then $F_n$ converges weakly to $F=\mathbb{1}\{x\ge 0\}$. The measures defined by $\mu_n((\infty,x])=F_n(x)$, and similarly for $\mu$, are an example.